# Why doesn't my shower work when it's below below 0?

Tags: shower

We had an addition put on in 2012. There are two bathrooms - one upper and one lower. Last winter the hot water in the upstairs bathroom quit working when it dipped below zero. This year, it worked all winter until a week ago when the weather dipped to -10 degrees. Then I had no water at all. We had one warmer day (20) during the week and it worked fine. Then it got to 17 below and it stopped again. My contractor checked and the insulation in the attic area was fine with no gaps.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's unlikely that the plumbing is in the attic, checking the insulation there is rather like checking the tire pressure when the oil light goes on in your car - unrelated, but you don't have to open the hood. Appears from afar to be a hack response by a contractor who doesn't care to get into the expense of actually correcting a problem that was almost certainly caused by poor construction practices (possibly exacerbated by poor design), especially for a 2012 build.

The problem will be where the pipes serving the area that stops working are. It will probably be something simple that was done wrong, such as running them on the outside of an insulated cavity (though arguably, in the experience of people from cold regions, running any plumbing in the outside walls is poor design, no matter where in the wall it is.) Fixing it properly will involve tearing walls open and putting them back together again, unless you are OK with plumbing that does not work when it's cold.